# Spring Boot Actuator does not start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

I added the spring boot actuator dependency to pom file but when I go to /actuator it displays whitelable page.I also visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862086/spring-boot-actuator-not-working) page but it did not help . What should do?

Because the stackoverflow was stuck, I removed some dependency from the pom.
Pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below line into your application.properties file

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

with this we can get all the actuators

Comment: I did that but it didn't work